# How to show all the text field dynamically values by loop or index flutter

Tags: flutter, entity-framework, flutter-layout, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

Hello everyone I have been trying to get the value from dynamic text fields values to the next screen here is the first screen code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < _nameControllers.length; i++) {
                              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                context,
                                CupertinoPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => TimeSheetPreviewScreen(
                                    name: _nameControllers[i].text, ====> this line is only showing single value not whole value
                                    // Helper
                                    //     .dropdownNameListForSelectClientScreen
                                    //     .toString()
                                    //     .replaceAll("[", "")
                                    //     .replaceAll("]", ""),
                                    startTime: "s",
                                    endTime: "getEndTime",
                                    showDate: "aa",
                                    decription: _descriptionControllers[i].text,
                                    totalLength: this.i,
                                    perHourRate: hourlyRateController.text,
                                    suppliesAmount:
                                        suppliesAmountController.text,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
```

But when I start a loop and show all the values from text fields to another screen here is the line

```
name: _nameControllers[i].text, ====> this line is only showing a single value not the whole value
```

This text field only shows a single value, not every textController field value.

here is the next screen code.

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:extended_masked_text/extended_masked_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:ole_app/screens/NewFinalScreen/TimeSheetScreen/pdfGenerationForTimeSheet/PdfInvoiceApi.dart';
import 'package:ole_app/screens/NewFinalScreen/TimeSheetScreen/pdfGenerationForTimeSheet/fileHandler.dart';
import 'package:ole_app/screens/NewFinalScreen/TimeSheetScreen/time_sheet_screen.dart';
import '../../../custom_widgets/Container_btn_with_gradient.dart';
import '../../../custom_widgets/appbar.dart';
import '../../../translations/locale_keys.g.dart';
import '../../../utils/controllers.dart';
import '../../../utils/helper.dart';

class TimeSheetPreviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  var name,
      startTime,
      endTime,
      showDate,
      decription,
      // showTime,
      perHourRate,
      suppliesAmount;

  final int totalLength;
  TimeSheetPreviewScreen({
    Key? key,
    this.name,
    this.startTime,
    this.endTime,
    this.showDate,
    this.decription,
    // this.showTime,
    this.perHourRate,
    this.suppliesAmount,
    required this.totalLength,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TimeSheetPreviewScreenState createState() => _TimeSheetPreviewScreenState();
}

class _TimeSheetPreviewScreenState extends State<TimeSheetPreviewScreen> {
  final hourlyRateController = MaskedTextController(mask: '000');
  // final suppliesAmount = MaskedTextController(mask: '000');

  final myStyle = TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    fontSize: 22.sp,
  );

  final myTotalStyle = TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    fontSize: 30.sp,
  );
  // var listItems = Helper.selectedItems.toString().replaceAll('[', '');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => Helper.onWillPopFunc(
        context: context,
        className: const TimeSheetScreen(),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar(
            title: LocaleKeys.timeSheetPreview_txt.tr(),
            fun: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const TimeSheetScreen(),
                )),
            elevation: 0),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.w),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  LocaleKeys.details_txt.tr(),
                  style: myStyle,
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  height: 60.h,
                ),

                ListView.separated(
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: widget.totalLength,
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                      const Divider(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                      Helper.index = index;
                      if (kDebugMode) {
                        print("index  =====>  " + index.toString());
                      }
                    });

                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "${LocaleKeys.name_txt.tr()}: ",
                              style: myStyle,
                            ),
                            Text("${widget.name}"),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15.h,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "${LocaleKeys.startTime_txt.tr()}: ",
                              style: myStyle,
                            ),
                            Text("${widget.name}"),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15.h,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "${LocaleKeys.endTime_txt.tr()}: ",
                              style: myStyle,
                            ),
                            // Text(
                            //   ControllersTextFields
                            //       .instance.invoiceNoController.text,
                            // ),
                            // Text("${widget.endTime}"),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15.h,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "${LocaleKeys.date_txt.tr()}: ",
                              style: myStyle,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              // DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(widget.showDate),
                              "${DateTime.now()}",
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15.h,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "${LocaleKeys.description_txt.tr()}: ",
                              style: myStyle,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              widget.decription,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15.h,
                        ),

                        Helper.customSizedBox,
                        const Divider(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        // Helper.customSizedBox,
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),

                // ============================
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "${LocaleKeys.time_txt.tr()}: ",
                      style: myStyle,
                    ),
                    const Text("5.5 Hours"),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.h,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "${LocaleKeys.perHourRate_txt.tr()}: ",
                      style: myStyle,
                    ),
                    Text("\$${widget.perHourRate}"),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.h,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Supplies Amount: ",
                      style: myStyle,
                    ),
                    Text("\$${widget.suppliesAmount}"),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40.h,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "${LocaleKeys.total_txt.tr()}: ",
                      style: myTotalStyle,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.h,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "${LocaleKeys.totalTime_txt.tr()}: ",
                      style: myStyle,
                    ),
                    const Text(''),
                    // "${Helper.calcWorkHours(widget.startTime, widget.endTime)}"),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.h,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "${LocaleKeys.totalAmount_txt.tr()}: ",
                      style: myStyle,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      '224',
                    ),
                    // "\$${Helper.calculateTotalAmount(double.tryParse(widget.startTime)!, double.tryParse(widget.endTime)!)} ")
                  ],
                ),
                // ============================
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100.h,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
          height: 180.h,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    CustomContainerButton(
                      text: LocaleKeys.downloadInvoice_text.tr(),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Helper.showAllDataForEverything;
                        setState(() {});
                        // generate pdf file
                        final pdfFile = await PdfInvoiceApi.generate(
                            weekEndingDate: widget.showDate,
                            name: widget.name,
                            description: widget.decription,
                            amountBilled: widget.perHourRate,
                            invoiceNo: ControllersTextFields
                                .instance.invoiceNoController.text);

                        // opening the pdf file
                        setState(() {
                          FileHandleApi.openFile(pdfFile);
                        });

                        // Helper.calcWorkHours(widget.startTime, widget.endTime);
                        // final date = DateTime.now();
                        // final dueDate = date.add(const Duration(days: 7));
                        // final invoice = Invoice(
                        //   supplier: Supplier(
                        //       name: "AHmed",
                        //       address: "karachi, johar town",
                        //       paymentInfo: "sddddddddd"),
                        //   customer: Customer(
                        //     name: "AHmed",
                        //     address: "karachi, johar town",
                        //   ),
                        //   info: InvoiceInfo(
                        //     date: date,
                        //     dueDate: dueDate,
                        //     description: "sddddddddddd",
                        //     number: "${DateTime.now().year}-9999",
                        //   ),
                        //   items: [
                        //     InvoiceItem(
                        //       description: "Coffe",
                        //       date: DateTime.now(),
                        //       quantity: 3,
                        //       vat: 0.19,
                        //       unitPrice: 5.99,
                        //     ),
                        //     InvoiceItem(
                        //       description: "Water",
                        //       date: DateTime.now(),
                        //       quantity: 3,
                        //       vat: 0.19,
                        //       unitPrice: 5.99,
                        //     ),
                        //     InvoiceItem(
                        //       description: "Orange",
                        //       date: DateTime.now(),
                        //       quantity: 3,
                        //       vat: 0.19,
                        //       unitPrice: 5.99,
                        //     ),
                        //   ],
                        // );
                        // final pdfFile = await PdfInvoiceApi.generate(invoice);
                        // PdfApi.openFile(pdfFile);\
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40.h,
                    ),
                    CustomContainerButton(
                      text: LocaleKeys.cancel_txt.tr(),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          CupertinoPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const TimeSheetScreen(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      isActive: false,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Future openFile(File file) async {
  //   final url = file.path;
  //
  //   await openFile.open(url);
  // }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I think the problem is with the Navigator.pushReplacement. When you use replacement all previous pages on the Navigator stack will be replaced by the last one. If you have many TextControllers, only the last one will be shown. Try to change your view, or use Navigator.push instead

Answer (score 0):

When you call  Navigator.pushReplacement in for loop, at index one it break the loop and navigate to new screen and that is cause this issue.

**Update:**
try this:

```
String text = '';
_nameControllers.forEach((element) => text = text + element.text);
```

then Navigate like this:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                context,
                                CupertinoPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => TimeSheetPreviewScreen(
                                    name: text,
                                    
                                    startTime: "s",
                                    endTime: "getEndTime",
                                    showDate: "aa",
                                    decription: _descriptionControllers[i].text,
                                    totalLength: this.i,
                                    perHourRate: hourlyRateController.text,
                                    suppliesAmount:
                                        suppliesAmountController.text,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
```

Comment: eamirho3ein thank you for help but basically, _nameControllers is basically the List<TextEditingController>    

  List<TextEditingController> _nameControllers = [];

that's why _nameControllers.text.characters.toList();     in this .text is not recognized

Comment: ooo my bad. I thought it is one controller. so you have a list of textfield, where are you doing this for loop?

Comment: eamirho3ein yes I have  List<TextEditingController> and I need to show all the values

Comment: Yes eamirho3ein, I understand the issue that when I call Navigator.pushReplacement in for loop, at index one it break the loop and navigate to new screen and that is cause this issue.


I need the issue to be resolved

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly.tell where and why do you call that for loop?

Comment: So basically I have a List<TextEditingField> and a List<TextFormField> When I click a button it shows a dynamic text field of name. Now what I'm doing is that I am showing Controller values like _nameControllers[i].text

Comment: here i is a loop variable that shows a different controllers value but when I navigate to next screen is shows only last picked value.

Comment: ok. at the same time you can navigate only once. you can not perform navigate in for loop. you want to merge all this controller text and pass them as one text to next page?

Comment: Yes I want to perform that how can I solve this issue please help me

Comment: How do you want to merge them? text1+text2+text3?is this ok?

Comment: I updated my answer. check it out. it merge all controller's text and make it as one string.

Comment: basically I want to show the data with its index in another screen let suppose in PDF View using flutter by passing all controllers values

Comment: unfortunately I don't understand what you want.